# Running Hudson on developer workstation using working copy of code

Tags: hudson

I haven't set up Hudson before and I'm hoping someone can tell me if what I want to do with it is feasible or not.

I'm writing code that will collect metrics during a Hudson build.  This code will be part of our functional test code for the project.  I want to test this code in Hudson before checking the code in so I don't break the Hudson build that the rest of the team uses.  I'll also be doing further development, testing, and tuning of the code so having my own Hudson instance as a "development" sandbox will be helpful for that too.

My question has to do with using my working copy of the code in Hudson.  Can I set up a local instance of Hudson on my workstation and have it use my working copy of the code base instead of doing a checkout from source control?  The code I want to test won't be in source control yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this in the project configuration by selecting None for SCM and in the shell command section adding a "cd d:\myproj" before running the .bat file that runs my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can select not to fetch from an SCM, specify which Ant build file to run from, which script to run, or which directory to run Maven from - anywhere on your file system.

In addition, you can specify where to pick up test results, collect metrics directly from your code, or collect metrics directly from console output - for publishing in Hudson/ Jenkins.